# How to pipe terminal interaction with running process over network?

Tags: networking, pipe, remote, netcat, pty

How can I run a program that expects to be executing in a terminal in such a way that it's STDIO can be arbitrarily connected-to remotely?

Specifically, I want to be able to launch gdb on one host and connect into it's terminal interface remotely, such that I can pause execution with CTRL+C, change the layout (e.g. `layout regs`), etc. The diagram below illustrates what I'm trying to accomplish.

[image: Connecting to GDB client remotely]

So far, the closest I've gotten is to use `socat` on the remote host to create the pty and start gdb:

```bash
$ socat PTY,link=$HOME/somedev,rawer, SYSTEM:"gdb 2>&1",pty
```

Then pipe that PTY to/from a netcat listener:

```bash
$ cat ~/somedev | nc -l 5556 > ~/somedev
```

And on the workstation, start netcat:

```bash
$ nc <remote_host> 5556
```

What I have at this point is close to what I want, but the terminal interaction is a bit wonky (e.g., if I change gdb's layout, it looks okay at first, but new lines coming in mess up alignment of the windows, etc.), and CTRL+C does not get forwarded through to the gdb process to suspend the process.

I admit, some of this behavior is probably due to limitations with netcat - I'm open to other programs to make the connection to the tcp listener on the remote host.

Some other constraints for a solution:

- The gdb process must begin independently of a remote connection being established (in other words, I can't use socat to start the gdb process, as in `socat TCP-LISTEN:5556,reuseaddr,fork EXEC:"gdb"`). This also eliminates solutions that involve running gdb on the workstation rather than the remote host.
- CTRL+C entered on the workstation terminal must cause `SIGINT` to be sent to the gdb process.

Answer (score 1):

The standard solution to connect to a remote host is [SSH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Shell) and I don't see anything in your question that rules it out. Terminal forwarding is a built-in feature of SSH.

> The gdb process must begin independently of a remote connection being established

For that, start it inside a [screen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Screen) or [tmux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tmux) session. Then use SSH to connect to that session.

---

Netcat only forwards data. The interface of a terminal includes more than the data exchanged over the terminal: it also requires handling [ioctl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ioctl#Terminals) calls, otherwise certain features don't work, like allowing the application to query the terminal's size, as well as input translation such as translating <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> to a SIGINT signal. [Socat can do it](https://blog.stalkr.net/2015/12/from-remote-shell-to-remote-terminal.html) if you call it right, but it's a lot easier with SSH.